# logit logitgof perdidos en R

Tags: missings

He realizado una regresión multinomial con `multinom()` del paquete nnet.

`reglog <- multinom (cl3 ~ sexo + edad  + mens + educ + pana + reg +vivie, data = datos)`

Para calcular la log likelihood goodness of fit quiero utilizar la función `logitgof()` del paquete generalhoslem.
`logitgof(datos$cl3, fitted(reglog))`

El problema es que me sale el siguiente error:

> Error in data.frame(obs, cutyhats) :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 18153, 16529

Entiendo que es por los NA, que no coinciden las filas del dataframe con la los "fitted" de la salida de multinom. He probado con todas las opciones del parámetro `na.action` pero no logro resolverlo. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias!